# Action Bar item Not responding on First click

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm having a strange problem in my action bar there is a share button, But its not working when it is first clicked when the app launches but after first it works without any problem. Here is my Code.

```
 @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     int id = item.getItemId();
     switch (id){
        case R.id.action_settings:
        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
               final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about_us);
                dialog.setTitle("About Us");
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                TextView textView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.aboutus);
                textView.setText("blah blah blah");
                Button button = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();

                return false;
            }
        });
            break;
        case R.id.share_action: item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
                localIntent.setType("text/plain");
                localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", "blah blah blah");
                localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", "FLAMES");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, "Share"));
                return false;
            }
        });
            break;


}
return false;}
```

Here is Screenshot.[App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk3H8.png)

And i forgot both the Action Bar Menu_items are acting same.
please give any solutions.

Comment: Are you sure that the app is ready when you click? Do you wait enough for app to be initialized?

Comment: No, app works fine. just both Menu_items not works on first click, but from second click they work normal.

Comment: but it is what your code should do ... on first click you are setting `setOnMenuItemClickListener` on next click it will execute the click listener callback ... seems like you do not understand basic code flow

Comment: @Selvin i can't understand what you are saying. If the problem is what you get. So what i should do to make it work on first click.

Comment: @ShivPandey: Is there a reason for this `new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener()` in the `onOptionsItemSelected()`? A simpler version of the code would look like: `switch (item.getItemId()) { case R.id.action_settings: final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);.... // rest of the switch cases}`

Comment: @Selvin Thank you very very much, now i get it.

Comment: @IceMAN As i'm new to android so i implemented it like a button So that's my mistake. sorry for the silly question. :p

Answer (score 0):

The OnMenuItemClickListener will automatically be called when the menu item it is associated with is clicked and so will the function onOptionsItemSelected when **any** menu item is clicked.

So you don't need to do both. Either set your task inside the OnMenuItemClickListener or inside the onOptionsItemSelected.

For example the onOptionsItemSelected must look like this :

```
@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 int id = item.getItemId();
 switch (id){
    case R.id.action_settings:

           final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about_us);
            dialog.setTitle("About Us");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            TextView textView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.aboutus);
            textView.setText("blah blah blah");
            Button button = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();

            return false;
        break;

    case R.id.share_action: 

            Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
            localIntent.setType("text/plain");
            localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", "blah blah blah");
            localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", "FLAMES");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, "Share"));
            return false;
        break;

}
return false;}
```

Comment: Thanks i fixed it, after selvin's answer.